# How to get to file source path while uploading a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I have trying get full path of uploading file, but i can't take that.
My code is here

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file">
```

Javascript code

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("file").value);
```

output

```
C:\fakepath\image.jpg
```

I want to know full path of the file.

Comment: Why do you want the local file system path?

Comment: _“I want to know full path of the file”_ – well, you can’t. It’s a security/privacy issue; just because I upload a file to your server, doesn’t make my local file system structure/folder names any of your business.

Comment: Ask Users to use IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has no powers to access the file system from the client end (Browser). Its all about security reasons.

But using HTML5 File API, only Firefox has a `mozFullPath` property, Even it will return null if you try to get the value of the file path.  So i can say that you cant get the file path.

Please refer the following link also.

[Link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav/15201258#15201258)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get full path of uploading file.
Browsers have a security feature that prevents JavaScript from knowing your file's local full path. It is good that as a client, you don't want the server to know your local machine's filesystem. It is good if all browsers does this from the security point of view.

Comment: Then how can i get file path? Using server only ah?

Comment: Why do you want the local file system path?

Comment: No, you can’t do this server-side either, the local path will not be send, only the local file name. (Unless the user explicitly instructs their browser otherwise, I remember f.e. IE having a setting for that.)